# How partitioning and clustered by works in Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I'm trying to understand below query by using that how data is going to be placed.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( 
         name string,
         city string,
         employee_id int ) 
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, day STRING) 
CLUSTERED BY (employee_id) INTO 256 BUCKETS
```

The keyword `PARTITIONED BY` will distribute the data in below like dir structure.

```
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/y=2015/m=12/d=02
```

But am not able to understand, how `employee_id` will be distributed among these directories ? 256 buckets (files) will be created, and all those files will be having all `employee_id` but which file will sit under which dir, how that will be decided ?

Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories are partitions or table location. Buckets are files inside these directories.

Complex partitions are hierarchical directories. In your case:

```
`/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/` - Table location, contains partition directories:
  `y=2015/` - year partition directory, contains months directories: 
    `m=12/` - month partition, contains days partitions directories:
      `d=02/` - day partition, contains 256 files(buckets)
        00000
        ...
        00255
     `d=03/` -Each day partition will contain 256 files (if you have enough data)
        00000
        ...
        00255
```

Each file will contain not all employee_id. Which record will sit in which file is decided using this formula:

```
 bucket_number=hash_function(employee_id) MOD 256
```

Where `hash_function` is integer, in case of Int `employee_id` it is equal to employee_id.

`256` - is the number of buckets

`MOD 256` will produce integer values in the range [0..255], corresponding to bucket numbers.

The same id's will always be in the same buckets. Each daily partition will contain it's own files(buckets), up to 256 buckets in each.

Say, employee_id = 1024 goes into bucket 0, if the same employee_id exists in many days, it will be in file 00000 in each day directory.

`employee_id=1050` goes into file 000026 because `1050 MOD 256 = 26`.

So, first the data is partitioned by partition key, inside partitions it is bucketed (distributed between files).